# Jenkins commit SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins

I faced a challenge. We plan on using Jenkins as an continuous integration service and need to commit dlls from jenkins to svn. We were able to find extremely few information on this. Could anyone provide as a link with relevant data or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't have a function like Checkout... so you need to do your commit inside a bat command. Ex : `bat "cd C:\jenkins\test && svn commit -m \"Commit to svn\" --username Hello --password Hello123"`.

Comment: No problem OlKol :)